# Div takes place above the other div?

Tags: css, html

You can look here:
http://jsfiddle.net/vsjwww/n7kk3/17/

It all works fine, but as you see, the div, which will slide down, starts slide above the other div.

It looks like a CSS problem, how can we solve it?

Thanks..

Comment: You have the div that you want to slide down contained within the div you don't want it to overlap?  Is there a specific reason?

Comment: @KyleRogers actually that's the way to do it.  It consolidates it and makes the slider's position relative to its trigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ad6ax/)

You need the dropdown div to have the following css:

```
#will_slideDown
{
    position:absolute;
    top:100%;
    left:0px;
}
```

and `#has_hover_function` needs `position:relative;`

Comment: or #will_slideDown {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
}

Comment: @OlaTuvesson hm... good idea but that makes it slide up instead of down.

Comment: Oh does it? Haven't used jQuery's slideToggle() - can't see why top:100% should make it behave different though?

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely position the inner element at the bottom border of the outer element:

```
#has_hover_function, #will_slideDown
{
   position:relative;
   width:150px;  
   height:25px;
   font-family:Arial;
   text-align:center;
   padding-top:3px;
   border:1px solid gray;
   background-color:#e7e7e7;
}

#will_slideDown {
   position:absolute;
   top:29px; /* 1px + 3px + 25px; */
   left:0;
}
```

Comment: Another great answer.. Thank you so much..
but I want to ask you to learn; what changes between top:29px and top:%100 ?